# Noether current of Dirac field

Tags: operators, fourier-transform, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

Under $U(1)$ symmetry of the Dirac Lagrangian I get, up to a constant, a current
$$j^\mu=\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi.$$
How can I express it using creation and annihilation operators? For example it's easy for $\mu=0$ but for $\mu=i$ I don't know how to proceed.

I can write
$$\psi=\int d\phi_k\left(\sum_ia_i(k)u_i(k)e^{-ikx}+\sum_ib^\dagger_i(k)v_i(k)e^{ikx}\right)$$
so
$$\bar\psi\gamma^0\psi=\psi^\dagger\psi=\int d\phi_k d\phi_{k'}\left(\sum_{i}a^\dagger_i(k)u^\dagger_i(k)e^{ikx}+\sum_ib_i(k)v^\dagger_i(k)e^{-ikx}\right)\left(\sum_ja_j(k)u_j(k)e^{-ikx}+\sum_jb^\dagger_j(k)v_j(k)e^{ikx}\right)$$

Now I have to multiply and use the identities for example
$$u^\dagger_iu_j=2E_k\delta_{ij}$$ $$u_i(k)^\dagger v_j(-k)=0$$
How can I proceed with $\mu=i$? I have to evaluate
$$\bar\psi\gamma^i\psi=\psi^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^i\psi=\int d\phi_k d\phi_{k'}\left(\sum_{i}a^\dagger_i(k)u^\dagger_i(k)e^{ikx}+\sum_ib_i(k)v^\dagger_i(k)e^{-ikx}\right)\gamma^0\gamma^i\left(\sum_ja_j(k')u_j(k')e^{-ik'x}+\sum_jb^\dagger_j(k')v_j(k')e^{ik'x}\right)$$

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried ?

Comment: Thanks, I added a sketch of my calculations

Comment: What is $\phi_k$ ? And I have the impression that you forgot a prime on the $k$ (one should apply $k \rightarrow k'$ ) in the second bracket of the double integral. Finally you can further expand the integrand getting sum of $Ca^\dagger a + D a^\dagger b^\dagger + E b a + F b b^\dagger$. Once one sandwiches the whole expression between particle states usually  only one term of these survives. Integrals of combined the exponential functions give typically delta functions.

Comment: Yes I forgot the prime just here when copying. The $d\phi_k=d^3k(2E_k(2\pi)^3)$. Ok so the expression can't be further simplified?

Comment: related, for the geometrical properties of the current:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219950/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219874/226902

Comment: I want to mention that you forget the normal ordering operation. i.e. $:j^{i}:$.