# Derivation of covariant derivative of Spinor

Tags: differential-geometry, differentiation, spinors, dirac-matrices

I am following [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04821) derivation for the covariant derivative of spinors. I have some questions about this derivation:

1. On page 3 they use the fact, that
   \begin{align*}
   V^a(x) = \bar{\Psi}(x)\gamma^a\Psi(x)
   \end{align*}
   transforms as a vector. Its not specified what exactly $\bar{\Psi}(x)$ means. Is it the conjugate transpose of $\Psi$? It definitely cant be the complex conjugate of the spinor since it has to be a row vector.
2. I also dont get how they come up with the equality in Equation (19). When I use the parallel transport equation above for the spinor I come up with
   \begin{align*}
   S(x+dx)-S(x) = -\bar{\Psi}(x)[\Omega_\nu(x)+\bar{\Omega}_\nu(x)]\Psi(x)dx^\nu
   \end{align*}
   Where do the gamma matrices rise from?
3. In equation (21) the third equality arises from the definition of the spin connection
   \begin{align*}
   V^a(x+dx)=V^a(x)-\omega^a_{b\nu}V^bdx^\nu
   \end{align*}
   as they say in the next sentence. If I use this I end up with
   \begin{align*}
   = -\omega^a_{b\nu}\bar{\Psi}(x)\gamma^b\Psi(x)dx^\nu
   \end{align*}
   and I cant see, why they dont have the spinors in their result. I assume that all of the problems I have resulting due to the same mistake.

Edit:

I found in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/219874/how-to-show-that-bar-psi-psi-of-a-dirac-spinor-psi-transforms-as-a-scalar?rq=1) post, that $\bar{\Psi}=\Psi^\dagger\gamma^0$. This solves problem 1 and 2. But I still cant solve problem 3.